# ArcEngine in WPF -> publish -> creates .msi install file -> installer fails

Tags: arcgis-engine

I am trying to install my custom ArcEngine application on another machine.  I just uninstalled and reinstalled ArcGis Engine Runtime 10 and authorized it.

"Unable to install or run the application.  The application requires that assembly ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework Version 10.0.0.0 be installed in the GAC first"

The weird thing is that a previous version of my application still runs.

Even the most long-shot type advice is welcome.  I'm hitting a wall.

---

I removed the reference to ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework, I guess I wasn't using it.  So I thought that would fix the problem, but actually the problem persists.  So I assume that one of the assemblies I use is dependant on Framework.  On the target machine, I went to the assembly directory and there is no Framework assembly on that machine and there is on my machine.  So short term quick fix is to get the assembly on that machine, I am installing devkit on the target to see if that gives me the assembly I need.

Comment: For each of the ESRI assemblies referenced in your project, do you have "specific version" set to false?

Comment: Also, what do you have in your app that uses the framework assembly?  An app intended to run under an arcengine license shouldn't use that assembly.

Comment: Kirk, it is a very common myth that the "specific version" switch in VS has any effect on the emitted assembly. It merely tweaks the way VS resolves assembly references in your project and has nothing to do with the steps taken by the CLR when resolving references at runtime. Bindings can also be specified in the configuration files. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the SDK to get the assemblies, although I think maybe I could have copied them.  Once I had the necessary assemblies I used the gacutil program to put them into the GAC.  I found it unusual that the ESRI installer did not auto register the necessary DLLs into the GAC.

Comment: You might want to verify that this doesn't violate the license agreement.